# Image not resizing Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using the Bootstrap 3 framework to create a prototype, I have a logo image in my header of my website that doesn't seem to be resizing at all. I have given it the image-responsive class but it doesn't affect it.

I think the column may not be holding the image content. I have created a fiddle (with a sample header image off google)

http://jsfiddle.net/pocockn/52VtD/10157/

```
<!-- navbar and logo -->
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class = "row nav-row">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src ="http://slant.investorplace.com/files/2013/08/pandora-stock-logo.png" class="img-responsive"></a>
                         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
      </div> <!-- end of col md 8 -->
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
                <li><a href="home.html">ROOMS</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">PROFILE</a></li>
                <li><a href="artists.html">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
       </div> <!-- end of col md 4 -->
      </div><!-- end of row -->
    </div><!-- end of container -->
```

Thanks!

Comment: You forgot to save your fiddle, it's the skeleton BT3 jsfiddle link you wrote...

Comment: Sorry, should work now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6zryf0ed/1) Try This
I Added class "logo" to img tag and "remove_pad" to a tag

```
 .logo{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.remove_pad{
    padding:0px !importnat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*One way is to override directly your `img` with css* :

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/62uz5odq/

```
.navbar-brand > img {
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: That seems to still not make the image larger and smaller on various screen sizes